# How to manually balance unbalanced multi-class/multi-label data?

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, multi-class, multilabel

I have a multi-class **and** multi-label classification problem, *i.e.:* each sample can have more than one label associated to it and there is a total number of `M` possible labels.

*e.g.:*

- `y[0] = [0]`
- `y[1] = [0, 1]`
- `y[2] = [1, 4, 3, 0]`
- `y[3] = [0, 1]`
- ...
- `y[100] = [1, 0, 3]`

Counting the number of occurrences of each label, I can see that some labels are **way** more frequent than others. In the example above, for instance, `0` appears more often than `1`, `3` and `4`.

I can't figure out a smart (over-)sampling strategy to have a dataset where each label appears approximately the same number of times.

Any papers/idea on that?

Comment: Count the frequencies of all the labels in a table and use these as weights?

Comment: Here is a paper that discusses the same problem: Giraldo-Forero, et al (2013). Managing Imbalanced Data Sets in Multi-label Problems: A Case Study with the SMOTE Algorithm, J. Ruiz-Shulcloper and G. Sanniti di Baja (Eds.): CIARP 2013, Part I, LNCS 8258, pp. 334–342 ([pdf](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-642-41822-8_42.pdf))

Comment: Good news! Class imbalance is not a problem! 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he
https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/
https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/ 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359936/247274 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/proper-scoring-rule-when-there-is-a-decision-to-make-e-g-spam-vs-ham-email
https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en

Comment: Why do you want to balance the data manually? Automation seems appropriate to me once you have a conceptual understanding of the process.

Answer (score 1):

Since each sample can have more than one label associated with it one possible solution would be to train $M$ logistic regression models, where the response variable for label $i$, sample $n$, is $Y_{i,n}$ where $Y_{i,n}=1$ if sample $n$ belongs to class $i$ and $Y_{i,n}=0$ if it does not.

For a new sample $Z$ your model output can be interpreted as the probability $Z$ belongs to each individual class.

Comment: and from there, see the links in Dave's comment: at least to start, do nothing about the imbalance (per label) and work with the predicted probabilities